# Can I get service for my Windows PC iTunes at a Genius Bar?

Tags: itunes, windows

I have a general question to ask.

If I have iTunes running on my Windows PC, and something was wrong, could I bring it into the Apple Store's Genius bar for them to service it?

Do they service Apple software outside of Apple hardware?

Comment: easy way to find out - call your local Apple Store and ask...

Comment: ... and after calling your local Apple Store please share it with others answering your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Apple retail stores support iTunes on PC. The depth of troubleshooting is typically deleting iTunes and associated applications from PC and re-downloading iTunes. That said many people have received great how-to info regarding iTunes on PC or Mac in Apple retail stores

Answer (score 0):

I went to the Apple store and asked my questions.

They do offer *some* service for iTunes on a PC. They just won't go beyond anything iTunes-- example the registry or other driver issues. So if it's very much a PC issue, they don't address those. I would think it would be similar to their web browser Safari.

As for service for Apple software on non-Apple hardware, say Mac OS X on an [hackintosh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSx86), they will not service.